# Center a view inside of a custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have noticed plugging in x,y coordinates in the mobile arena is a dangerous idea. My x,y coordinates look great on 4s and 5s, but look off on 6. I'm very close centering, but haven't quite nailed it yet. Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
        - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        float imgWidth = 100;

        float imgHeight = 80;
        self.showImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.contentView.bounds.size.width/2)-(imgWidth/2),15,imgWidth,imgHeight)];



        [self.contentView addSubview:self.showImage];
      ;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: look into the `CGRectGet` functions. This looks like a good place for `CGRectGetMidX()`.

Comment: Why don't you use auto layout?

Comment: Occasionally,  there's certain instances where auto layout gets in my way. That's why I prefer to programmatically position certain views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone 4S and iPhone 5S both have the same width (320 pts). The iPhone 6 is 375 pts wide and the iPhone 6+ is 414 pts wide. So if you're not using the scaled version of your app for both the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+, you can't be setting your frames manually and expect them to center correctly.

Quick/dirty option:

- Check `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width` and manually change frames accordingly

Better option:

- Use [AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)